# Vector graphics are smaller in file size and more scalable than raster, why vector graphics are not used more often in web and mobile app development?

Tags: web-development, web-applications, mobile, user-interface, user-experience

As in the topic. If yes - why, if no - why? I never seen it recommended in any android/web development tutorials to use vector graphics instead of your usual PNGs and JPGs and I find it odd.

I checked just now and eBay UK (as an example of a very popular and professionally made website) doesn't accept SVG images as item images. Is it because technically it's difficult to implement, or am I missing something here?

My other thought is that maybe if vector graphics were more popular, that could lead to people using their SMART TVs more often as a computer screen?

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that eBay is generally designed to sell real items, not abstract art or computer renderings. The vast majority of all computer graphics are rendered vector graphics. Websites may prefer certain formats for maximum compatibility, but Flash - once a wildly popular platform - was predominantly vector graphics iirc.

Comment: some of the assumptions are a bit off - vector graphics can be smaller in size, but its not guranteed

Answer (score 5):

## Cameras don't draw.

That is the by and large of it. Photo's are not drawn, and anything compositing a photo into it still has that not a drawing issue.

## Processing and Bandwidth aren't free

A drawn image still has to be rasterised for display on a rastered device such as monitors, and most printers. That requires computation, and many devices are slow/inefficient/unsupportive of it.

It also has to be communicated to the device. There is a break even point were the raster is smaller than the drawing. Which happens to be at smaller sizes, and also happens to correlate with devices that need smaller sizes, and are on the worst internet connections.

## Not everything can handle drawings.

Most software works well with raster formats like png. There are still many pieces of software that have issues with vector formats like svg. Thus they can export a small library of different sizes once and have them just work, or they have to work around all of these edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

One likely reason to not allow uploads of SVG files is that they support embedded [scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/script).  These could potentially be used for XSS or other nefarious purposes.  Personally, I think it was a mistake to make this a feature of SVG for precisely that reason.

Answer (score -1):

What I know is, Picture contains pixels (stored information which doesn't need processing before showing up) contrary to vectors which are not just stored information of pixels but contains a way **how to process to get image**. This way of processing to get an image is not always preferred due to computation cost unless we need a **scalable image** (no quality decrease on zoom/scaling).

Hope it help. though I do not know much.